# How do I type the pipe symbol on a Swedish keyboard?

Tags: linux, unix, keyboard

Being a Linux user, as most Linux users, I use the pipe symbol (`|`) daily.

I'm currently sitting at a Swedish keyboard. There are three keys on the keyboard that (together with an orgy of four or five other symbols) have the pipe symbol on it:

[image: Swedish keyboard with pipe symbol highlighted]

But for the life of me, I can't figure out how to make the pipe symbol materialize on the screen, and no amount of *alt-gr-ing* seems to get me there.

How can I type the pipe symbol (`|`) on a Swedish keyboard?

Comment: I have such annoyances, even with a UK keyboard. If you're on Ubuntu (and possibly other Debian derivatives) you can open **System Settings** -> **Text Entry**: at the bottom right of the list of input sources there is a keyboard icon. If you click on this it will show you the keyboard map and it will highlight each key you press. This will confirm which key codes are sent from each of the keys with the current keyboard map.

Comment: That is one hell of a messy keyboard :D

Comment: try RIGHT `alt+7`??

Comment: @RahulBasu That results in `{` (which by the way, is also a key I type hundreds of times a day and is really annoying to press, especially since I'm used to a US keyboard)

Comment: Do you have `AltGr` key? Maybe the right side Alt with the key next to the backspace?

Comment: I wonder if the keyboard is for another Scandinavian country. By the way, the keyboard layout can be displayed with `gkbd-keyboard-display -l se`.

Answer (score 16):

- **Danish**: <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd>+<kbd>´`</kbd> found to the right of <kbd>+?\</kbd>.
- **Norwegian**: <kbd>§½</kbd> found to the left of <kbd>1!</kbd>.
- **Norwegian with Sami**: <kbd>§½</kbd> found to the left of <kbd>1!</kbd>.
- **Swedish**: <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd>+<kbd><></kbd> found to the left of <kbd>Z</kbd>.
- **Swedish with Sami**: <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd>+<kbd><></kbd> found to the left of <kbd>Z</kbd>.

If you couldn't get a single `|` by using Alt Gr, you are most likely using the Norwegian layout.

Answer (score 2):

The keyboard layout is not "Swedish", it's the "Nordic" layout, used in Denmark, Norway, Sweeden and such. I'm not sure if it works with Linux, but on Windows with the Danish layout, it's "Alt Gr" + the key to the left of the backspace.

[image]

Comment: +1 for specifying that the keyboard is scandi (Norsk, Swedish, Danish), and not just "swedish"

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Windows 10, configured with a Swedish keyboard and for me, I press <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> and the <kbd><>|</kbd> key (the key in the red box at the bottom left of your diagram).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with Fedora 26. I used to get the pipe character when Fedora 23 was installed with <kbd>AltGR</kbd> + <kbd><>|</kbd>. But instead of `|`, it outputs `ı`, which is `i` without the dot ("idotless").

Using xev, I saw:

```
KeyRelease event, serial 36, synthetic NO, window 0x5400001,
    root 0x296, subw 0x0, time 1097943857, (464,363), root:(509,472),
    state 0x80, keycode 31 (keysym 0x2b9, idotless), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 2 bytes: (c4 b1) "ı"
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

I used xmodmap to fix it back:

```
$ **xmodmap -e "keycode 31 = i I i I bar brokenbar"**
```

(it was `keycode 31 = i I i I idotless bar`)

Now it works.
And xev now shows:

```
KeyRelease event, serial 36, synthetic NO, window 0x5400001,
    root 0x296, subw 0x0, time 1099965050, (534,-197), root:(534,404),
    state 0x80, keycode 31 (keysym 0x7c, bar), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (7c) "|"
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

Answer (score 1):

It is an old question, but since nobody gave the easy answer:

> <kbd>alt</kbd> + 124

124 is the decimal equivalent for the `|` character in the ASCII table.