# How to type an approximately equal (≈) sign on Swedish keyboard pipe?

Tags: keyboard, special-characters

How to type an approximately equal (≈) sign on Swedish keyboard pipe?

Kept getting re-directed to this issue when googling for a solution:
[How do I type the pipe symbol on a Swedish keyboard?](https://superuser.com/questions/973442/how-do-i-type-the-pipe-symbol-on-a-swedish-keyboard)

Comment: Does [5 Ways to Type Approximately Equal Symbol (≈) in Word/Excel - Software Accountant](https://softwareaccountant.com/approximately-equal-symbol/) answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

The `≈` character does not exist in the ECMA-Latin-1 (= ISO-8859-1) character set.
The same is true for Windows CP1252; Ref: https://sv.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252.

So <kbd>Alt<kbd>+`247` will not produce it.</kbd></kbd>

Linux:

```
$ python -c 'print("\xf7")'
÷
$ python -c 'print(ord("\xf7"))'
247
```

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd> `2248` <kbd>Enter</kbd> does produce it on Linux,
so the corresponding `2248` Alt+x should make it appear in Windows.

Ref:
https://softwareaccountant.com/approximately-equal-symbol/
... appears to be somewhat wrong.

Comment: Apparently order is important... Thanks!
Both works:
    (a) Holding Alt and then typing 247 works
    (b) First typing 2248 then pressing Alt + X

Comment: If 'Alt 247' do create the `≈` then that is "odd", as it isn't present in the character set. Now that is assuming the old age CP1252 though, maybe things has changed.